# Action Script 3 Error after upgrade to Flash CS6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I recently upgraded to Flash CS6 from CS4.  I didn't receive any errors with this script until CS6 but now I'm receiving the following error:

Symbol 'wholePlayer,Layer,'Layer9'Frame 3 Line 12 - 1152 A conflict exists with inherited definition flash.display:movieclip.isPlaying in namespace public.

Here's my script:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;

stop();

// Create the sound object
var snd:Sound = new Sound();
// Assign a var name for the sound channel
var channel:SoundChannel;
// Initialize the pause position
var pausePosition:int = 0;
// Boolean value for button functions, to switch in the conditionals

var isPlaying:Boolean = false;  ******HERE'S THE LINE REFERENCED IN THE ERROR*******

// Set the play buffer to 5 seconds, you can adjust this
var context:SoundLoaderContext = new SoundLoaderContext(5000,true);
// Load the requested URL sound into the snd var, along with context
snd.load(req, context);
// Create the play channel using snd
channel = snd.play();// Start playing
// --- Stop sound from autoplaying --- \\
if(firstTime == true)
{
    stopSound(null);
}
```

It's script for an .MP3 player.  I've indicated the line that's mentioned in the error above.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Solan

Comment: did you try changng the false to a 0?

Answer (score 3):

Version 11 of the Flash Player added a MovieClip property named *isPlaying*. Renaming your variable will solve the problem.